# instagram with flash security error

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to access instagrams API with FLash, I keep getting a "Security sandbox violation: cannot load data from https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=...etc" but it works in the IDE. It is loading the cross domain policy file from https://api.instagram.com/crossdomain.xml and I have security allow api.instagram.com in the swf. Any thoughts? Am I stuck using a backend proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using :

Security.loadPolicyFile("https://api.instagram.com/crossdomain.xml");

Possibly try swapping out the https with http? Probably not the right solution.

Otherwise, yes, try the proxy back-end solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've encounered the same problem while trying to access Instagram API from as3 application located on the remote server. I've tried something like http://my-secret-domain.com/app and got the exception.

The solution was to access my app through **https**, exactly like the app accesses the Instagram API. The only thing I didnt get is why the Flash Player cares about https for request that is made **after** the app was loaded to local mashine using http.

Answer (score 0):

Closely follow the guidelines for registering your client and authorization process available on [developer authentication page](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/). It covers everything necessary to access the API. If you are building native AIR app implicit authentication will be good choice, choose explicit server side auth for alternative development strategy.